# Javascript md5 hash of image to compare with Java

Tags: java, javascript, md5

I am getting a different hash from javascript then I do from java ... I am hoping someone can explain and help to correct this.

**The History**
I am trying to connect to a third party from a mobile app.. I am having to rewrite their java api into javascript which is causing some translation problems.  One of the issues is that they are expecting a data array of an image and an md5 hash of that image for comparison.  In Java when I use their code I get a different hash to when I do the same thing in javascript.

In java, the code:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(testimg,  Base64.DEFAULT);

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
md.reset();
md.update(decodedString);

byte[] array = md.digest();
```

creates a hash of: ad5e3cdf9174167243ded0e329a37cf6

the same thing in javascript gives: 8bd54f4d1c4800e3df9cdd2aee728ded

```
var decodedstr = window.atob(testimg);
var hashString = MD5(decodedstr);
```

In javascript I cannot pass a byte array as with java, but the byte values should be the same (although java displays these as unsigned)

How can I change my image array in javascript to create the same hash and still have a proper image?

Comment: What do you mean by "the byte value of this"? The hash gives a byte array, not a single byte. Please show your Java code. Note that to convert a string into bytes requires an encoding - and you *definitely* shouldn't be using that for an *image* conversion. Images aren't text - don't treat them as if they were.

Comment: Expanding on the previous comment.  There is no one to one relationship between bytes and characters, so statements like this: "the first byte in my test image is 'ÿ'" don't even make sense.  The byte, or bytes, that encode that character, or any character, depend on what character encoding you use (ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16, ShiftJS, etc).

Comment: Thanks, have changed my query to hopefully be a bit clearer.  I am working with a base64 image which I then decode to a byte array.  By looking at the arrays of each they are essentially the same (although java shows as unsigned.  javascript MD5 algorithms tend to only accept strings rather than arrays so by using atob I assumed this would decodes the image into a usable string since performing a charcodeat on the resulting string matches with the java array (although signed).  Sorry if am confusing the issue.

Comment: After your update, the java code now looks ok.  The javascript seems suspicious.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.atob  says that atob is "For use with Unicode or UTF-8 strings", meaning it is going to assign the javascript var "decodedstr" not bytes, but UTF-8 characters-- as mentioned, given UTF-8 characters created from *arbitrary/image* bytes there is no way to go back to the same bytes.

Comment: Assuming the content of **testimg** really represents the bytes of the image, then what you would want to do is call MD5(**testimg**), skipping the conversion of the image bytes to a string.

Comment: Thanks Keith.. After the earlier comments I thought I was somehow mixing something up. finally got it to work but after your comment Im not exactly sure how. found a new md5 script at http://blog.faultylabs.com/?d=md5 that will allow me to pass in an arraybuffer.  I am creating my arraybuffer from the charCodeAt of 'decodedstr' generated by atob.  This creates an identical hash as the java file.  Will have a bit more of a play though.  cannot close the query for another 5 hours so might find a better solution.  Btw.  I dont think I can pass testimg as this is a base64 hash not the bytes.

Comment: @Keith, no it says _"For use with Unicode or UTF-8 strings, see this note at Base64 encoding and decoding and this note at window.btoa."_, which is very different.

Comment: The issue here is that there is no native MD5 function in Javascript.  Since internally Javascript can represent strings in different ways (UCS2 or UTF16), and there's no standard way to represent a byte array, implementing MD5 can be "interesting".  Likely what you're seeing is that the implementer of the MD5 function you're using made some choices that are incompatible with your particular situation, for example, for each character in the string they may have passed the entire 2 bytes into the MD5 algorithm, which would produce a completely different result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it!  Thanks guys for your help and comments.  For anyone else who stumbles upon this: Eventually found an MD5 script at: http://blog.faultylabs.com/?d=md5 that will allow me to pass in an arraybuffer and that resolved it.

Or at least, gave me the desired result, Sounds like there is just a lot more trial and error with javascript as everything is handled a bit differently to other languages.

Thanks again.

Comment: This link is out of date now, can you please post a permanent answer. Thanks